# Using pandas, I want to be able to highlight cells which contains "-->" in csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

I am using excel to open .csv files. I cannot download excel packages like openpyxl as it is not my server.
When I open csv file through excel it does give me option to conditionally format it. So I am hoping to be able to do it through python code.

I tried the following code but it didn't work

```
# def highlight_cells(val):
#     color = 'yellow' if val.contains("-->") else ''
#     return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
#
#
# df1.style.applymap(highlight_cells)

df1.style.applymap(lambda x: ["background: red" if v.contains("-->") else "" for v in x])
```

Kindly guide if it is possible or not.

Other issue that I am facing is that I want to be able to delete second row of my csv file using pandas but I am unable to do so.
I tried the following code:

```
df1.drop(df1.index[[1]], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: once you have loaded the file, you have a dataframe.  The fact that the source was excel or csv is unimportant.  Try to phase the question in pandas terms

Answer (score 0):

df1.drop([1,],axis=0, inplace=True)

try this to delete the second row